# Python. Чем на самом деле является print?

Tags: python, python-2.x, print, expressions

Почему функция/оператор/набор символов (или что оно на самом деле) `print` не может работать в выражениях?

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('hahaha')
hahaha
>>> 0 or print('hahaha')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0 or print('hahaha')
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def test(): print('hahaha')
... 
>>> 0 or test()
hahaha
>>>
```

Comment: это будет работать если воспользоваться функцией `print()` из "будущего": `from __future__ import print_function`. В Python 3 - это работает по умолчанию...

Comment: @MaxU, то есть, `print` в Python 2.X, не замещенный объектом из `__future__ `, это макрос?

Comment: `print` в Python 2.x по умолчанию это `statement` - не знаю как грамотно перевести на русский... `print(1,2,3)` - это просто `print` в который передали кортеж `(1,2,3)`, по-моему. Если же воспользоваться функцией из Python 3, то все это отрабатываеи по-другому...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В Python 2.X `print` является ключевым словом (вроде `return` во многих языках), по этому после него выражение не обязательно должно быть заключено в скобки. И оно не является функцией и не может возвращать значения (даже `None`). По этому оно не может быть частью логического выражения:

```
0 or return("hahaha")
```

В Pyton 3.X это фнукция. По этому там требуется ее аргументы заключать в скобки, и она возвращает `None` (который в логическом контексте действует как `False`), по этому такое логическое выражение не вызовет ошибок.

Comment: `or` также является ключевым словом. Это не мешает `or` оператору возвращать значение, участвовать в выражении. `print`-конструкция (Питон 2) ничего не возвращает, не может как значение использоваться (иногда "print statement" как "print инструкция" или "print оператор" переводятся). Можно превратить print в функцию `from __future__ import print_function`, тогда слово `print` уже функцию будет означать (или что угодно, так как можно другой объект в этом случае прицепить: `print = 1`).

Comment: Да, jfs, вы правы, хорошее замечание